# Node js return old data from twilio account to angular component

Tags: node.js, angular, twilio

I tried to run function from Angular each 10 seconds to find out my twillio account balance.

When I run backend from cmd, first result is ok, then in the background cron send SMS on some mobile phone. But when function from Node is called after 10 seconds, it always return my first balacne before sending SMS on mobile phones. Does it have something common with cache?

My angular function to call service and Node js function

```
  getTwilioAccountBalance() {
      this.twilioService.getTwilioAccountBalance().subscribe({
        next: data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.accountBalance = Math.round((data.balance*0.94 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
          console.log(this.accountBalance);
        },
        error: err => {
          console.log(err)
        }
      })
    }
```

Node js function in controller what send balance from Twillio account

```
require('dotenv').config();


exports.getTwilioAccountBalance = (req, res) => {

const client = require('twilio')(process.env.ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.AUTH_TOKEN)

client.balance.fetch()
  .then((data) => {
    const balance = Math.round(data.balance * 100) / 100;
    const currency = data.currency;
    console.log(`Your account balance is ${balance} ${currency}.`)

    res.status(200).send({
        balance
      })
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  
};
```

If i wanna to receive current balance of my account, I have to turn off backend in cmd and run it again

Comment: There's a simple trick to always get refresh request is append the time in the request query. Something like: `api/get_balance?t=currentTime`, this way every request will be a new request, browsers won't cache it. You can also open DevTool Network tab to check if the request is actually cached